# .entry-title will not change in blog post on wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, blogs

I'm currently having difficulties changing the post title font family within a blog post.

I've tried the following selectors singularly in the custom CSS plugin for WordPress:

```
.entry-header .entry-title
.entry-title h1
.entry-title
.entry-header
.page-id-107 .entry-title
.page-id-107 .header
.entry-header h1
```

Now here is the real confusion, if I use the following code:

```
.alpha, h1 {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 3em;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-family: Georgia;
}
```

This will change the post title on page: [*'Charlies online store'*](http://charliesonlinestore.com/blog/)

But if you go into an actual post such as: [Charlies online store post](http://charliesonlinestore.com/men-learn-women-warm/)

It does not change. Why?

I would really appreciate any help here.

Comment: Looks to me it is because you have inline styles in the head of the document which would be why your external styles are not overriding.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using the wrong selector.

`.entry-title h1` would target an `h1` element that's a descendant of an element with the class `entry-title`

`h1.entry-title`could be the right selector for what you're trying to achieve (change an h1 element with the class entry-title)

I tried this in the Inspector and it should be working, however so should `.entry-header h1`; so I'm not entirely sure what's wrong.

You might also need different selectors for the two pages, because on one the text is directly in the `h2` tag while on the homepage, it's additionally wrappend in an `a` tag.

Comment: Thank you. 

I've tested h1.entry-title and.entry-header h1 
but It still doesn't change the post title.

Maybe there is another selector I'm missing?

Comment: If it helps, I was able to use:

.page-id-331 .entry-title {
   font-family: Georgia;
   font-size: 1.3em;
   line-height: 1.2em;
}

 To change the homepage post title.

 I have tried selecting the post id for the blog post
and running the above code but this doesn't do anything either :(

Comment: Weird, could you try adding the rule with `!important`, like so: `h1.entry-title {
    font-size: 1.3em !important;
}`

This might not be the prettiest solution, but just to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your section with this one below, your current section on actual post page is overwrite that why it isn't work.

```
.alpha, .post h1.entry-title { // Changing elements on this two pages from your description
    font-size: 1.3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-family: Georgia;
}
```

or if you want change all H1 tag then

```
.alpha, .site-main h1 { // Changing H1 tag on whole website
    font-size: 1.3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-family: Georgia;
}
```

Comment: Inline styling in the head may be the problem. Might need to use

Comment: Tested it and this above should overwrite head styles.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly after replacing the code with yours.

So there was a conflict because of the old code? Interesting.

Comment: That good! about conflict, point is in it, which section was more important.